# Is 「として」 seen as 「と+して 」？

Tags: definitions

として is translated in dictionaries as meaning something like "as" or "in the role of".

I'm curious if Japanese speakers see this word as one word, or is it seen as having some relation to と+して (i.e., quote particle + する)?

Comment: Not criticizing or anything but I’m curious how you plan to use this information. What difference do you think it makes to you as a learner whether native speakers see it as one word or two?

Comment: It helps me understand Japanese grammar a bit better.

Comment: It clearly consists of と and して if you grammatically analyze it, but it doesn’t mean native speakers are conscious of it when we speak and let alone what function this と plays. (I doubt it’s quotative.) I was wondering how this helps a learner understand grammar better.

Comment: @aguijonazo That native speakers don't consciously think of this as two separate words answers my question. It means there's no deeper grammatical structure worth understanding here.

Comment: But when specifically asked, some will say it is related to と and して (because it is). When I ask a similar question about “instead of”, some English speakers might kindly explain to me it is related to “in”, “stead”, and “of”. If this is too much dissection, how about “in place of”? The proportion of such native speakers might increase. But I don’t think that helps me, as a learner, better understand how to use those expressions. Depending on the way you ask these questions, you might not get what you are looking for. I thought the same about your other question about それで.

Comment: Why are you discussing the purpose of this question here? Is it really too much to ask for information that has no immidient use for a learner? Learning of examples from Japanese could help to build connections, see differences and in general compare languages which is always helpful.

Comment: @ChristelleAugustin - Because these questions are hard to answer and possibly opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. XをYとする is a related construction.